# Saving Actions from your action panel

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

I have just made a complicated set of actions for my workflow and want to save them on an external drive and also add them to a laptop. Can anyone tell me how to do this in simple terms. Thank you.

Comment: For better reference you should tag the program you are using.

Answer (score 5):

- Open the Actions Panel *Window -> Actions*

> The action needs to be saved in a folder, as you can only export a folder of actions, not the action itself.
>
> (You can call the folder the same name as the action - to make it easier to find)
>
> <sub>Thanks @Ovaryraptor for reminding me of this.</sub>

- Click on the drop-down menu (top right)

[image]

- Select *Save Actions*

(this will give you the option to export your actions)

---

Comment: It's worth noting that the action MUST be in a folder to save otherwise you can't perform this. Please update your answer.